# Passing data to a closure in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use the Mail Class in Laravel 4, and I'm not able to pass variables to the $m object.

the $team object contains data I grabbed from the DB with eloquent.

```
Mail::send('emails.report', $data, function($m)
{
   $m->to($team->senior->email, $team->senior->first_name. ' '. $team->senior->last_name );
   $m->cc($team->junior->email, $team->junior->first_name. ' '. $team->junior->last_name );
   $m->subject('Monthly Report');
   $m->from('info@website.example', 'Sender');
});
```

For some reason I get an error where $team object is not available. I suppose it has something to do with the scope.

Comment: Exact same scenario for me. The Mail::send issue lead to me searching about passing variables to closures and then back to this. Perhaps a sign something needs to be added to the laravel mailer docs on this?

Answer (score 251, accepted):

If you instantiated the `$team` variable outside of the function, then it's not in the functions scope. Use the [use](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) keyword.

```
$team = Team::find($id);
Mail::send('emails.report', $data, function($m) use ($team)
{
   $m->to($team->senior->email, $team->senior->first_name . ' '. $team->senior->last_name );
   $m->cc($team->junior->email, $team->junior->first_name . ' '. $team->junior->last_name );
   $m->subject('Monthly Report');
   $m->from('info@website.example', 'Sender');
});
```

*Note: The function being used is a [PHP Closure (anonymous function)](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) It is not exclusive to Laravel.*

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize you could use 'use' like that.  I only wish I could have learned this sooner.

Comment: Also worked to solve my problem with Maill::queue in Laravel 5

Comment: @DavidHyogo Me too, glad to find this post

Comment: and also works for advanced search to manage $query->where and orWhere in Laravel 7.  Thanks