# eager loading pass variable in withCount where condition

Tags: laravel

```
$user = 1;
                       
Forum::with(['posts' => function($query){
    $query->withCount(['comments => function($query){
            $query->where('id_user', $user); 
        }]);
}])
->get();
```

How to pass the value of the $user variable to `$query->where('id_user', $user);`

$user is not working (appears underlined in red in the editor).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482102/passing-data-to-a-closure-in-laravel-4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass argument in callback function in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035355/how-to-pass-argument-in-callback-function-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user = 1;
                       
Forum::with(['posts' => function($query) use ($user){
    $query->withCount(['comments => function($query) use ($user){
            $query->where('id_user', $user); 
        }]);
}])
->get();
```